# Registering open generics in asp net core with instantiation of implementation class

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, database-connection, repository-pattern

I have a class library which holds my generic repository class `IRepository<T>`. Whenever I need a repository in my asp.net core web project I just instantiate `IRepository` with the given type and I can use it normally. However to do this I need this in my `StartUp.cs`:

```
services.AddScoped<IRepository<SomeType>>(x => new DocumentDbRepository<SomeType>(new DatabaseSettings(
                Configuration.GetSection("DocumentDb").GetSection("DatabaseName").Value,
                Configuration.GetSection("DocumentDb").GetSection("CollectionName").Value,
                Configuration.GetSection("DocumentDb").GetSection("EndpointUri").Value,
                Configuration.GetSection("DocumentDb").GetSection("Key").Value)));
```

I don't want to do this for every type `T`, is there a generic way to do the above?

I tried to do the following:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof (IRepository<>), typeof(DocumentDbRepository<>));
```

which is what I'm looking for but I need to instantiate `DocumentDbRepository` with database settings that it needs.

Right now I'm extracting from `appsettings.json`, putting the values into my class `DatabaseSettings` and then giving this in to the constructor of `DocumentDbRepository`.

My question is really twofold:

1) Is it possible to instantiate the implementation part of the open generics types that is provided? I.e. `DocumentDbRepository`?

2) Is there a better way to pass db settings to my repository? I have tried to pass IConfiguration object to the constructor of the class library but I cannot seem to resolve the IConfiguration reference in the class library, as it seems IConfiguration is a part of asp net framework?

**I'm using asp net core on top of .NET framework (not .NET core).**

Edit:

The section fields are the same for every type i.e. all repositories needs to be instantiated with the same settings. Is this a bad design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are the section fields different for every type? If not why not just make a generic method that calls all this stuff for you?

```
    public void doIt<T>()
    {
    services.AddScoped<IRepository<T>>(x => new DocumentDbRepository<T>(
new DatabaseSettings(Configuration.GetSection("DocumentDb").GetSection("DatabaseName").Value, 
Configuration.GetSection("DocumentDb").GetSection("CollectionName").Value, 
Configuration.GetSection("DocumentDb").GetSection("EndpointUri").Value, 
Configuration.GetSection("DocumentDb").GetSection("Key").Value)));
    }
```

If they are different you could pass the strings as parameters to your generic method.

Comment: I don't understand, where would you invoke doIt<T> from?

Comment: Your startup.cs is where ever you currently invoke services.AddScoped<IRepository<SomeType>> from. Just replace with doIt<SomeType>; You could stick this in a factory class and hookup a dependency container to call it when it needs an object each type of interface you require.